# Passing AD authentication credentials via IE browser in C# Windows Form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, internet-explorer, windows-authentication

We have a Windows Form application which hosts an IE browser control. Our users run the application and open links to documents stored in MOSS. We are trying to set the application up to pass in credentials of a service account so that we can avoid giving all users access to the MOSS site. We have used code found [here](http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.windows.inetexplorer.ie5.programming.components.webbrowser_ctl/browse_thread/thread/8a7f5038432f328e) which seems to work fine if the user is not currently signed on to our domain. However the application will not seem to pass in the service account authentication for any user which is already authenticated to the domain. In this case it just seems to use the authenticated users credentials.

How can we make this work?

Comment: Why not just give "Everyone" access to the SharePoint site or put all the users that need access to the site in an AD group and then add that group to the SharePoint site.  Impersonation sounds like a hack in this situation.

Comment: Jeff: sorry for the dup, I deleted the post, as I did not open thye link you provided.

Comment: spoon16 - So far we gave everyone access but we don't want to for audit reasons. The access to the information is controlled through application which opens the Windows Form and we'd rather not let users get access to the MOSS site directly, but instead use the service account.

Answer (score 2):

Under what Internet Zone does the website you are pointing to run under?  Even if you are using your own browser control, it will still be in some zone.  Determine what zone it is by using a normal browser to go to the relevant site, and determine what zone it is in.
                                                  [alt text http://img219.imageshack.us/img219/7162/internetzonenp8.jpg](http://img219.imageshack.us/img219/7162/internetzonenp8.jpg)

If that specific zone has the automatically log in, it will take your logged on credentials.  If however you are not logged on as a valid domain user, then those local windows credentials are not accepted, and it seems to fall back on your code supplied credentials. 
                                                   [alt text http://img230.imageshack.us/img230/407/settingskm3.jpg](http://img230.imageshack.us/img230/407/settingskm3.jpg)

If security is not a big concern, perhaps it makes sense to run your existing web page under an application pool, running under the service account credentials.  Remember to add the service account to the worker process group, and take the integrated authentication feature off.

I have from past experienced learn that is generally is more robust, and maintainable by adding a global group into a local group, and perhaps giving that local group permission on the server.  But the real world is sometimes messy and that is certainly not always practical or the best solution.

I hope that this answers some of your questions, but I dont think it will answer all of it.  If there is a spesific area that you would like more info and if I can answer it, I would be glad to help.

Best Regards
Rihan

Answer (score 0):

Would impersonation not help here? You can run that bit of code (the form) under the guise of the service account user you're talking about and the browser control should then run within the same context.

the following links might help;

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b80a7e92.aspx

http://www.buro9.com/blog/2006/10/06/impersonating-a-user-in-c/

Comment: Unfortunately impersonation doesn't seem to help. The impersonation works (based on the code snippet from the blog mentioned) but the IE browser control ignores the impersonation and still authenticates to my MOSS site with the underlying AD user, even if control is instantiated after impersonation.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that the IE control in your application will automatically sign-in to the MOSS site, based on the credentials in the Windows session. You would rather it always used an account you specify, and coded into the application?

IE automaticlly signs in to domain sites using a type of Kerberos authentication (Windows Integrated Authentication)

Three suggestions;

- Do not use the MOSS site's WINS name but IP-address instead (may also work with DNS names e.g. not http://moss-server but http://moss-server.domain.com). This
  should cause IE to not automatically sign in to the site.
- Change the authentication model on the web-server to use Basic
  only (security warning - clear text
  password exchange)
- Disable the option for 'Enable Integrated Windows
  Authentication' in the web-browser.
  This will make accessing any sites
  in the domain a pain...

My recommendation is the 1st one. Use a different address to make IE think it is not accessing a trusted site and therefore not use integrated authentication.

All can be tested using IE outside of the application. Simple fire up IE and enter the address you are using to the MOSS site. If you are asked for a password, you have your solution.